# simplifying $\min(\max(A,B),C) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a larger problem, I have to make use of the following
$$\min(\max(A,\ B),\ C)$$

Please how do I simplify?

Comment: I don't think you can simplify this further, unless you know some inequality between $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: I am seconding Andrew's comment.

Comment: Is it possible to simplify if we let $B=80$ and say, $C=100$?

Comment: Maybe you want to expand using the distributive law?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood how's that done?

Comment: So instead of writing (a*(b+c))=((a*b)+(a*c)) if we put all function symbols before argument, we can write *a+bc=+*ab*ac.  Similarly, min(max(A, B), C)=max(min(A, C), min(B, C)), and yes you can prove that min(max(A, B), C)=max(min(A, C), min(B, C)) and that max(min(A, B), C)=min(max(A, C), max(B, C)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna use the notation in stochastic caculus I saw sometimes, $max(A,B) = B + (A-B)_+$, then $$min(B+(A-B)_+, C) = C - (C - B - (A-B)_+)_+$$

Answer (score 1):

This does not simplify for arbitrary $A,B,C$, but a scenario where this often comes up is when $A<C$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\min(\max(A,B),C)$ has the *conceptual* simplification of reducing to $B$ unless $B$ is too high or low.

E.g. $f(x) := \min(\max(0,x),1) = x$ if $0\leq x  \leq 1$, otherwise it takes the extreme value it is closest to.

Answer (score 1):

For $a, b ∈ \Bbb R:$

$$\max\left(a,b\right) = \frac{a+b+\left|a-b\right|}{2}$$

$$\min\left(a,b\right) = \frac{a+b-\left|a-b\right|}{2}$$

Therefore, if  $a,b,c ∈ \Bbb R:$

$$\min\left(\max\left(a,b\right),c\right) =
 \min\left(\frac{a+b+\left| a-b\right|}{2},c\right)  = $$

$$=\frac{\frac{a+b+\left| a-b\right|}{2}+c-\left|\frac{a+b+\left|a-b\right|}{2}-c\right|}{2}=
\frac{a+b+\lvert a-b\rvert}{4}+\frac{c}{2}-\left|\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{4}-\frac{c}{2}\right|=$$

$$=\frac{a+b+\left|a-b\right|+2c}{4}-\left|\frac{a+b+|a-b|-2c}{4}\right|=$$
$$=\frac{a+b+\left|a-b\right|+2c-\Big|a+b+\left|a-b\right|-2c\Big|}{4}$$

Comment: This is an insightful answer, although it might not quite seem like a simplification. Please help others to read it by typesetting this in $\LaTeX$!